# calling a method in java and incrementing an array in a for loop

Tags: java, random

Hi i am new to programming, my program is a random number generator using the math.random class and i am having issues with my code. I need to Call the randInt method n times in the randTest method, each time incrementing the count of the element counts corresponding to the value returned. Basically each time a random number is generated, the counts element increases.

This is my code so far:

```
public class RandNumGenerator {

    public static int RandInt(){
        int n = (int) Math.random()*10;
        return n;
        }

    public static void randTest(int n){
        int [] counts = new int [10];

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            RandInt();

            }
            }
    }
```

Comment: why not just `int count = 0;` then you do `count++` inside the for loop?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to replace this line:

```
RandInt();
```

with:

```
counts[i] = RandInt();
```

Also, replace all the '10' by `n` in randTest method

Answer (score 1):

JFPicard is correct.  I'm just throwing in a little advice for your RandInt function that I was given when I first started out.

When you have a function like your RandInt function above that assigns the value of a computation to a variable and then returns that variable you can instantly return that value without assigning it to a variable first.  This helps keep your code succinct and lends to better readability.

Also, you can use the Random class to generate a random integer.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    // a random number generator seeded with the current time
    private static Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()); 

    /**
     * RandInt returns a random number between 1 and 100
     * @return
     */
    public static int RandInt()
    {
        // notice how we can return the result immediately without having
        // to assign the value to a variable first
        return rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] counts = new int[10];
        for(int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++)
        {
            counts[i] = RandInt();
            System.out.println(counts[i]);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("The random value for counts[%d] is %d\n", i, counts[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I take it you want to count how many of each number has been randomly generated.

I have also fixed your rand function because `(int) Math.random()*10` is not a good way of getting a rand in range [0..9].

```
public class RandNumGenerator {

    private Random rand = new Random();

    public int RandInt(){
        int n = rand.nextInt(10); //gives random in range [0..9]
        return n;
    }

    public void randTest(int n){
        int [] counts = new int [10];

        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            int r = RandInt();
            counts[r]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have to use the math.random class in this project

Comment: Are you sure they said math.random **class**? because that doesn't make sense, you've used `math.random` **function**

Answer (score -1):

I have 3 suggestions to make this easier for you.

First, your for loop needs to go from 1 to N

```
for(int i=0; i< n; i++)
```

Second, storing the return value from the RandInt function

```
int returnNum;
returnNum = RandInt();
```

Third, depending on your actual requirements (I'm unsure if this is what you intended) you can use a map to store the number of occurrences for each returned value
like...

```
Map myMap<Int,Int> = New Map<Int,Int>();
```

So all together, it would look like

```
Map myMap<Int,Int> = New Map<Int,Int>();
int returnNum;
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    returnNum = RandInt();
    if(myMap.get(returnNum) == null) //randomnumber hasnt been used et
    {
        myMap.put(returnNum,1);
    }
    else  //increase occurence of random number
    {
        myMap.put(returnNum,myMap.get(returnNum) +1);
    }
}
```

More about maps: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object)

Maps are very powerful tools and I would recommend learning them to a beginning programmer